# Updating state in reducer is not rerendering sub components

Tags: react-hooks, react-context, react-typescript

I have a reducer that is used to add data. The reducer have one action called 'SELECT_MODEL'. I had an issue where when changing the selectedModelId would not rerender the component tree and im not sure why.

This updated the state, but does not rerender (See case === 'SELECT_MODEL')

```js
export const dataReducer = (dataState: DataState, action: dataAction): DataState => {
    switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_MODELS':
        action.models.forEach((dataModel) => {
            if(!dataState.models.find(x => x.model.id === dataModel.model.id)){
                dataState.models.push(dataModel);
            }
        });
        if(dataState.models.length === 1){
            dataState.selectedModelId = dataState.models[0].model.id;
        }

        return dataState;
    case 'SELECT_MODEL':
        dataState.selectedModelId = action.id;
        return dataState;
    default:
        return dataState;
    }
};
```

This updated the state and triggers a rerender (See case === 'SELECT_MODEL')

```js
export const dataReducer = (dataState: DataState, action: dataAction): DataState => {
    switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_MODELS':
        action.models.forEach((dataModel) => {
            if(!dataState.models.find(x => x.model.id === dataModel.model.id)){
                dataState.models.push(dataModel);
            }
        });
        if(dataState.models.length === 1){
            dataState.selectedModelId = dataState.models[0].model.id;
        }

        return dataState;
    case 'SELECT_MODEL':
        return {...dataState, selectedModelId: action.id};
    default:
        return dataState;
    }
};
```

Im a bit lost as to why one version triggers the rerender and the other does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can read in React's documentation: **"Pitfall: State is read-only. Don’t modify any objects or arrays in state."** (https://react.dev/reference/react/useReducer#writing-the-reducer-function)

React checks if you return a new object when updating states with a comparison like `if (newState !== oldState) { refresh(); }`. If you just change some information within the old state, the new information will be used during any future refresh - but the next refresh itself will not be triggered automatically (because technically `newState === oldState`, it's the same object reference).

**BTW:** You have similar problems with your implementation of action "ADD_MODELS". Consider doing something like the following instead to make it easier for you to work with an updated state:

```
case 'ADD_MODELS':
    const newState = { ...dataState, models: [ ...dataState.models ] };
    action.models.forEach((dataModel) => {
        if(!newState.models.find(x => x.model.id === dataModel.model.id)){
            newState.models.push(dataModel);
        }
    });
    if(newState.models.length === 1){
        newState.selectedModelId = newState.models[0].model.id;
    }
    return newState;
```